# Why The Google Drive Realtime API model does not contain timestamps of every revision?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

The Realtime API "get" REST method (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get) could be very useful to reconstruct the history of a document, if only its response contained the timestamp at which every revision was generated.

Is there a way to retrieve this timing information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't currently possible.  We don't track timestamps associated with each each.